# Laravel Migration From Git -- White Screen Showing Only

Tags: php, git, .htaccess, laravel-4, migration

I developed a laravel web application and pushed to bitbucket GIT repository.

Now I reinstalled my ubuntu and setup apache2, php, and mysql and successfully installed new laravel using composer and it works fine for me.

But when I try to clone my old laravel web app from git, it is showing only a white screen.

The **Wappalyzer** showing laravel in their list.

MY Htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
composer update
```

Thanks